# A ground to ground projectile is at a point A at $t=\frac T3$ and at B at $t=\frac{5T}{6}$ and reaches the ground at $t=T$....

Tags: kinematics

> A ground to ground projectile is at a point A at $t=\frac T3$ and at B at $t=\frac{5T}{6}$ and reaches the ground at $t=T$. Find the difference in height between A and B.

Time of flight is $$T=\frac{2u_y}{g}$$ where $u_y$ is vertical component of initial velocity

Therefore

$$t_a=\frac{2u_y}{3g}$$and $$t_b=\frac{5u_y}{3g}$$

Then $$h_a=u_y t_a-\frac 12 g t_a^2$$
$$h_b=u_yt_b-\frac 12 g t_b^2$$

$$h_b-h_a=u_y(t_b-t_a)-\frac 12 g (t_b^2-t_a^2)$$
$$=(t_b-t_a)(u_y-\frac 12 g (t_b+t_a))$$
$$=\frac {u_y}{g}(u_y-\frac 12 g(\frac{7u_y}{3g}))$$

So I am getting a negative value, here. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong! Its totally fine that $h_b - h_a<0$. This simply means that $h_b<h_a$. That is, that in $A$ the projectile is higher than in $B$, which is intuitive, since in point $B$, the projectile is near from hitting the ground.